# Bootstrap dropdown not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the bootstrap dropdown working in my Ruby on Rails app nav bar.

I am including the correct javascript file.s

Here's the code:

```
<div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=>"dropdown"><%= link_to current_user.first_name, profileshow_path(current_user)%></div>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path%></li>
                       <li><%= link_to "Your Profile", profileshow_path(current_user) %></li>
                       <li class='last'><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
                    </ul>





<script>
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the `>` from `data-toggle=>"dropdown"`. It is just `data-toggle="dropdown"` in HTML.

Comment: @spickermann that did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Bootstrap before, but looking at the example in the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example) it feels to me like your nesting is not correct.

Please try:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <%= link_to(profileshow_path(current_user),
              :class => 'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle',
              :data  => { :toggle => 'dropdown' }) do %>
    <%= current_user.first_name %>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  <% end %>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <%= link_to("Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path) %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to("Your Profile", profileshow_path(current_user)) %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these script elements. Take out:

```
<script>
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
```

and replace with:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```